# How to inject a component into root component from a child component?

Tags: reactjs, notifications

How to inject a component into root component from any of a child component?

For eg. i have this below code that is working fine.

```
import { ToastrNotification } from './mycomponents';

export const MyComponent = (props:any) => {
    return (
    <>
        <ToastrNotification>Hello!!</ToastrNotification>
    </>
    );
};
```

But i want to inject `ToastrNotification` to the root element from `MyComponent` using a code like below:

```
    const showNotification = () => {
        showToastrNotification({
            heading:"Success",
            info: "This is a success notification"
        });
    };
```

Here i need to know what code can i put in `showToastrNotification` so a notification component will appear in root element and not inside `MyComponent`.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by using a code below ? and what is `showToastrNotification` function ?

Comment: As per your question, I think you've to add components to some other dom node.
So Maybe you can use React Portal here. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Check this if it helps for your use case. Thanks!

Comment: @KavinduVIndika `showToastrNotification` is what i need, i don't know what code i put in function `showToastrNotification` to make my notification appear inside of root element instead of `MyComponent`. For eg. i call `showNotification` it will run code similar to what i write above `showToastrNotification` which in turn make `ToastrNotification` appear in root element.

Comment: @ShubhamJajoo Thanks i will look at it.